# How to perform soft deletes on an association mapping table in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, soft-delete

So although I personally hate soft deletes, im working in a project for which every table must only soft delete. Im not sure how to handle soft deletes on an association table, the field for which looks like this:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = AdvertisementVendor.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "advertisement_version_advertisement_vendor_association",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_version_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_vendor_id"))
private Set<AdvertisementVendor> _advertisement_vendors = new HashSet<>();
```

I've seen how to do [soft deletes](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/implement-soft-delete-hibernate/), but I'm not sure how I would apply that to the association table.

UPDATE:

Taking Dragan Bozanovic's advice I updated my column to:

```
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = AdvertisementVendor.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "advertisement_version_advertisement_vendor_association",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_version_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_vendor_id"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "is_deleted = 0")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE advertisement_version_advertisement_vendor_association SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE advertisement_version_id = ? AND advertisement_vendor_id = ?", check = ResultCheckStyle.COUNT)
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO advertisement_version_advertisement_vendor_association " +
        "(advertisement_version_id, advertisement_vendor_id, is_deleted) VALUES(?, ?, 0) " +
        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is_deleted = 0")
private Set<AdvertisementVendor> _advertisement_vendors = new HashSet<>();
```

<s>But this doesnt seem to be working. It seems to ignore @SQLDelete and just removes the mapping.</s>

UPDATE 2:

Ignore the first update, it had to do with different code. The above example works as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [@WhereJoinTable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/WhereJoinTable.html) for filtering conditions on join tables:

> Where clause to add to the collection join table. The clause is
>   written in SQL. Just as with `Where`, a common use case is for
>   implementing soft-deletes.

Comment: That solves 1 issue thanks, but there is also changing the delete on the join table to set delete flag, and also to unset delete flag instead of insert if something is deleted and then readded

Comment: @Mr.MonoChrome I assume that you could make [`SQLDelete`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLDelete.html) and [`SQLInsert`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLInsert.html) on collection level work for that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and while your solution does work, I also had to add an @SQLDeleteAll annotation in addition to @SQLDelete.

The problem I had is it was still calling the default delete statement when I cleared all entries from the HashSet or deleted the parent object.

Apologies if my terminology is a little off, I'm still pretty new to Hibernate.